# How do I assign a keyboard shortcut to a service in OS X?

Tags: keyboard, services

I created a service using Automator and I'd like to assign a keyboard shortcut to it. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **System Preferences**, go to **Keyboard** » **Keyboard Shortcuts** » Services

Find the service on the list.

To the right of the service name, double-click.

Enter the desired shortcut.

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me, not sure why. Tried very unique shortcuts using only modifiers and alphas (nothing odd like arrows). Tried relaunching Finder and event rebooting machine. Service works from contextual menu. ??? Mavericks.

Comment: Same. I would love to make use of this but seems like even though the settings app offers it, there is no one home listening for these hot keys in macOS?